# Q: Scrapy: Next pages not crawled but crawler seems to be following links

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to learn python and scrapy but I'm having problems with CrawlSpider.
The code below works for me. It takes all the links in the start url that matches the xpath - `//div[@class="info"]/h3/a/@href` then passes those links to the function *parse_dir_contents*.

What I need now, is to get the crawler to move to the next page. I tried to use rules and linkextractor but I can't seem to make it work properly. I also tried using `//a/@href` as the xpath for the *parse* function but it wouldn't pass the links to the *parse_dir_contents* function. I think I'm missing something REALLY simple. Any ideas?

```
class ypSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "ypTest"
download_delay = 2
allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/restaurants?page=1"]

rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['restaurants?page=[1-2]']), callback="parse")
]

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="info"]/h3/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        if 'mip' in url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)


def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="mip"]'):
        item = ypItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['business'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/h1/text()').extract()
        ---extra items here---
        yield item
```

**Edit:**
Here's the updated code with three functions and is able to scrape 150 items. I think it's a problem with my rules but I've tried what I think might work, but still same output.

```
class ypSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "ypTest"
download_delay = 2
allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/restaurants?page=1"]

rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'restaurants\?page\=[1-2]']), callback='parse')
]

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        if 'restaurants?page=' in url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_links)


def parse_links(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="info"]/h3/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        if 'mip' in url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)


def parse_page(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="mip"]'):
        item = ypItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['business'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/h1/text()').extract()
        item['phone'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/section/div/div[2]/p[3]/text()').extract()
        item['street'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/section/div/div[2]/p[1]/text()').re(r'(.+)\,')
        item['city'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/section/div/div[2]/p[2]/text()').re(r'(.+)\,')
        item['state'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/section/div/div[2]/p[2]/text()').re(r'\,\s(.+)\s\d')
        item['zip'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/section/div/div[2]/p[2]/text()').re(r'(\d+)')
        item['category'] = sel.xpath('//dd[@class="categories"]/span/a/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

`CrawlSpider` uses the parse routine for its own purposes, rename your `parse()` to something else, change the callback in `rules[]` to match and try again.

Comment: That didn't work. But it gave me an idea to create another parse() function that will get all the links on the page first then passes it to the original parse() which I will rename to parse_links() that will then pass it to parse_dir_contents(). Hope that works.

Comment: Okay, so it seems it's now scraping 150 items instead of just around 30. But  even if I increase the allow=['restaurants?page=[1-2]'] to allow more pages, it doesn't work. I also tried increasing the depth limit, but same output.

Comment: Progress at least. Could you post your latest code.

Comment: From the scrapy documentation here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules. You really shouldn't have a parse() method since the CrawlSpider uses it.

`When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.`

Comment: @JignoAlfredVenezuela, you are correct it is only scraping 150 items, 30 items per page. And this is because `LinkExtractor` rule is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late to answer this problem, but I managed to solve it and I am posting my answer cause it might be helpful for someone like me who was confused about how to use scrapy `Rule` and `LinkExtractor` in the first place.

This is my working code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ypSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ypTest"
    allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/restaurants'
             ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'restaurants\?page=\d+']), follow=True), # Scrapes all the pagination links 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='scrollable-pane']//a[@class='business-name']"), callback='parse_item'), # Scrapes all the restaurant detail links and use `parse_item` as a callback method
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'url' : response.url
        }
```

So, I managed to understand how `Rule` and `LinkExtractor` works in this scenario.

First `Rule` entry is for scraping all the pagination links and the `allow` parameter in `LinkExtractor` function is basically using `regex` to pass only those links which match the `regex`. In this scenario, as per `regex`, only links which contain pattern like `restaurants\?page=\d+` where `\d+` means one or more numbers. Also, is uses the default `parse` method as a callback. (In this, I could use `restrict_xpath` parameter to choose only those links which come under a specific region in HTML, and not `allow` parameter but I use it to understand how it works with `regex`)

Second `Rule` is for fetching all restaurants detail links and parsing those using `parse_item` method. Here in this `Rule`, we are using `restrict_xpaths` parameter, which defines regions inside the response where links should be extracted from. Here, we are fetching only those content which comes under `div` with class `scrollable-pane` and only those links which has class `business-name`, as if you inspect the HTML, you'll find more than one links to the same restaurant with different query parameters in same `div`. And in the last, we are passing our callback method `parse_item`.

Now, when I run this spider, it fetches all restaurant(Restaurants in New York, NY) details which are in total 3030, in this scenario.